# Bulk inserts into Kafka Streams application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a **stateful** Kafka Streams application that works just fine for streaming data. However, one of the sources performs a huge data exports periodically. In this case, the volume of data produced to Kafka exceeds the normal average and causes significant consumer lags in the streams processing.

I'm wondering, what are the possible approaches to handle such bulk inserts? Or is it only possible to wait till the data is processed and the lag is decreased?

I would assume the for such bulk/batch processing it is reasonable to create a parallel data flow. For example, using Spark. But in this case all data modifications performed in this "parallel flow" will not be reflected in the Kafka Streams state stores and inconsistency will appear.

Comment: The usual solution to this is to increase the number of partitions on the topic, make sure that you have some means of partitioning the input data (e.g. by customer key) , and also increase the number of stream threads or application instances of your Kafka Streams application. Obviously not all problems can be parallelized in this way, but most can.

Comment: have a check on this: https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer